# Get Year From Date string

Tags: php, html

I want to check whether the current year is greater than a date string(D-M-Y)  here is my code

```
$OldDate = "09-30-2011";
$OldYear = strtok($OldDate, '-');
$NewYear = date("Y");

if ($OldYear < $NewYear) {
    echo "Year is less than current year"   
} else {
    echo "Year is greater than current year";
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$OldDate = "2011-09-30";

$oldDateUnix = strtotime($OldDate);
if(date("Y", $oldDateUnix) < date("Y")) {
    echo "Year is less than current year";
} else {
    echo "Year is greater than current year";
}
```

**UPDATE**

Because you're using an unconventional datestamp, you have to use different methods, eg:

```
$OldDate = "09-30-2011";
list($month, $day, $year) = explode("-", $OldDate);
$oldDateUnix = strtotime($year . "-" . $month . "-" . $day);
if(date("Y", $oldDateUnix) < date("Y")) {
    echo "Year is less than current year";
} else {
    echo "Year is greater than current year";
}
```

**NOTE:** If you want to **always** be sure that your date gets correctly understood by `strtotime`, use **YYYY-MM-DD**

Comment: Be careful using strtotime however, you can get some confusing results if you expect US formatted dates and get British for example.

Comment: @scoota269 is right - and you can test this using `echo date("Y-m-d", $oldDateUnix)`. In this case, it even bugs up and results (1970-01-01) which is unix time 0. I've updated my top comment to fix and reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

use the date function to get year

```
$OldDate = date("Y",strtotime("09-30-2011"));
$NewYear = date("Y",strtotime("now"));

if($OldYear<$NewYear)
{
echo "Year is less than current year"   
}
else
{
 echo "Year is greater than current year";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal by doing:

```
$input_date = date("09-30-2011");
$input_date_arr = explode("-", $input_date);
$currYear = date("Y");
$inputYear = $input_date_arr[2];

if ($currYear > $inputYear) {
echo "Current year is greater than given year!";
} else {
echo "Current year is not greater than given year!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       $OldDate = "09-30-2011";
       $OldYear = date('Y',strtotime($OldDate));
       $NewYear = date("Y");
       if($OldYear<$NewYear)
        {
         echo "Year is less than current year"   
          }
        else
         {
          echo "Year is greater than current year";
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the string to a timestamp, and check it with the current timestamp

```
if(time($OldDate) < time()){
// do stuff
} else {
// do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do this,

```
$dateString = '2021-02-24';                     

$yr = date("Y", strtotime($dateString)); 
$mon = date("m", strtotime($dateString)); 
$date = date("d", strtotime($dateString));
```